# django: rendering a variable with safe filter without unicode 'u' type designator

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to pass a dictionary to a django template. In the django view, the variable is initialized and passed as such:

```
foo = {'a':'b'}
...
return render(request, 'template.html', {'foo': str(foo)}
```

In the template, I have

```
{{ foo|default:"{}"|safe}}
```

In case it's relevant, I have the above line in a jquery snippet. That snippet is failing because the dict is being rendered as

```
[{'a': u'b'}]
```

instead of what I expect:

```
[{'a': 'b'}]
```

It seems the safe filter is not removing the unicode u preceding the dict value 'b'. How do I do that?

Comment: `return render(request, 'template.html', {'foo': foo.encode("utf8")}`

Comment: @catherine does foo (a dictionary) have an encode method? I don't think so. In any case, i tried str(foo).encode("utf8"), and that still doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean to render the dict as JSON? If so, there are better options.

Comment: Hi @valtron, JSON would work, I believe. I'm really trying to generate a [formData](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata) array

Comment: Have you tried it in your foo not outside the foo `{'foo': str(foo.encode("utf8"))}`

Comment: encode is a built-in function for decoding unicode character so it's available to all variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using a function to explicitly convert it to JSON, because of a few subtle differences between JSON and the default Python stringification:

- A string in JSON technically must be delimited with `"` rather than `'`, though parsers tend to accept the latter too (see the string rule on [json.org](http://www.json.org/))
- Bool literals are lowercase
- If your data contains things other than numbers, strings, lists and dicts, using `str` on them will probably silently produce invalid JSON

Use a template filter such as [django-jsonify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/0.2.1):

```
{% load jsonify %}
...
{{ foo|jsonify }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was experiencing this problem was because my dictionary actually included a unicode value. The toy example above was a simplification. when i ran `str(val)` before inserting val into the dict, the rendering occurred as expected.